# AWS amplify Getting the owner data not only the Id

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Is something like this possible? How is this supposed to be designed for this use case? Do I have to add a lambda function that adds the user (`owner`) to the post when it is created?

Can anyone help me to accomplish that .. Thanks!

This is Post schema:

```
type Post
  @model
  @key(name: "byClub", fields: ["clubId"])
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete, read] }
      { allow: private, operations: [read] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  content: String!
  upVotes: Int!
  downVotes: Int!
  image: String
  clubId: ID!
  comments: [Comment] @connection(keyName: "byPost", fields: ["id"])
}
```

And when I fetch the post, this is what I got:

```
{
    "id": "xxxxxxx",
    "content": "xxxxx!",
    "upVotes": 0,
    "downVotes": 0,
    "image": null,
    "clubId": "xxxxxx",
    "comments": {
        "nextToken": null
    },
    "createdAt": "2021-12-05T10:46:59.797Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-12-05T10:46:59.797Z",
    "owner": "moneebalalfi@gmail.com"
}
```

I want something like this:

```
{
    "id": "xxxxx",
    "content": "xxxxxxx",
    "upVotes": 0,
    "downVotes": 0,
    "image": null,
    "clubId": "xxxxxxxx",
    "comments": {
        "nextToken": null
    },
    "createdAt": "2021-12-05T10:46:59.797Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-12-05T10:46:59.797Z",
    "owner": {
       name: "xxxxx",
       email: "xxxx@gmail.com",
       image: "xxxxxx",
       // and so on ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`owner` field is only used for checking if the requested user is the owner of the data.

> Owner authorization specifies whether a user can access or operate against an object. To do so, each object will get an `ownerField` field (by default `owner` will be added to the object if not specified) that stores ownership information and is verified in various ways during resolver execution.

[from Amplify Docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/auth/#owner-authorization)

To be able to make a connection with the user you need to create another GraphQL Type.

```
type User
  @model 
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete, read] }
      { allow: private, operations: [read] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
  image: String
}

type Post
  @model
  @key(name: "byClub", fields: ["clubId"])
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete, read] }
      { allow: private, operations: [read] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  content: String!
  upVotes: Int!
  downVotes: Int!
  image: String
  clubId: ID!
  owner: ID
  user: User @connection(fields: ["owner"])
  comments: [Comment] @connection(keyName: "byPost", fields: ["id"])
}
```

You might need to configure `amplify codegen` to increase the max-depth, if it's not showing.

```
$ amplify configure codegen 
$ amplify codegen
```